# iOS - Drawing Rectangles (CGRect) on UIImage in Swift not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, drawrect, cgrect

I am attempting to draw rectangles (array of CGRects) on a UIImage which will be rendered back to the end-user.
The final result, for lack of a better phrase, just looks weird. For example, if I have an array of 2 CGRect's, only one is drawn, barely, but not fully complete. The other is omitted. Please see image below for how the image turns out with a particular array of CGRects. (FYI: I am sending the image to Google Cloud for processing, which responds with an array of CGRects)

What am I missing?

```
private func drawOccurrencesOnImage(_ occurrences: [CGRect], _ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let imageSize = image.size
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale)

    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    ctx?.addRects(occurrences)
    ctx?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    ctx?.setLineWidth(2.0)
    ctx?.strokePath()

    guard let drawnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        presentAlert(alertTitle: "Error", alertText: "There was an issue, please try again")
        return nil
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return drawnImage
}
```

CGRect array ("occurrences" from function above) with a value of "[(298.0, 868.0, 65.0, 43.0), (464.0, 1017.0, 67.0, 36.0)]" results in image below:
[image: Screenshot of UIImage]

Further details: using Swift 4, iOS 12

Thank you!

Comment: I used exactly your code, but with other rects. It worked perfectly. It seems, x and y in your rects are too large. Can you double check that? Maybe you need to adjust rects somehow.

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy - thanks for the comment! Can you provide what other rects you used where it worked perfectly? Would be super helpful. & what phone were you testing on? Thank you a bunch.

Comment: I was testing on XS simulator. I tested with CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100) and CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100)

Comment: great - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is right .

"[(298.0, 868.0, 65.0, 43.0), (464.0, 1017.0, 67.0, 36.0)]"

Coordinates are not proper.

Please consider the iPhone Resolutions.

[image]

---

[image: img]

```
imageView.image = drawOccurrencesOnImage([CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 59, height: 60), CGRect(x: 120, y: 50, width: 59, height: 60)], UIImage(named: "person-placeholder")!)
```

[source](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

Comment: dengApro thank you for the response - great to know. So, it looks like the first 2 numbers of each CGRect (the x & y) are "out-of-bounds" then? Is this what is "not proper" about the coordinates specifically? (I.e. the width and height are OK?) Hmm, I wonder why, then, in my screenshot I sent there actually IS a little something drawn that I circled - what is your take on this?

Comment: x and y in your rects are too large.  agree with @Evgeniy

Comment: Upon further research, the reason for my drawing being all messed up is that I am sending JPEG/HEIC images to Google Cloud Vision API's for processing, which isn't working when drawing the rectangles. If, however, I use a SCREENSHOT (PNG), and then draw the rectangles, it works perfectly. Now I am looking at a way to somehow convert UIImages to PNG, or screenshots, or something......:/

Comment: you are handling photography ( .HEIC )